# CentOS Linux 7 cronjob validate the expression and check if it will run

Tags: centos, cron

I do have a CentOS Linux 7. On `/etc/crontab` I added my command that I want to run:

```
0 0 20 * * root MySpecificCommand
```

I do have three questions:

- How can I check if my expression is valid and and what time the next run is? I know in this case its maybe simple and you can say if its OK or not. But if it starts to grow, i want to validate my crontab entries, because the change to make any mistake increase.
- When I run `crontab -l` the result is empty. Is my expectation wrong, that it has to be listed there too?
- Any chance to list all planned cronjobs at once? Like these in `crontab`, `cron.daily`, `cron.hourly`, `cron.weekly` etc.?

Comment: To see crontab entry with `crontab -l` , you should enter it with `crontab -e`. Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203120/cronjob-entry-in-crontab-e-vs-etc-crontab-which-one-is-better what is the difference between `/etc/crontab` and `crontab -e`.

Comment: Your question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.